# Play the next audio song from API when user presses the next button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to create a music player, which will play music from API. In the player screen, there is the next button. When the user presses this button, it will automatically play the next song. But I can't play the next song.

I already tried some way.
But it just increases the next song by 5-10 seconds.

```
package com.example.diu.myaudio;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button backBtn, forBtn;
private Button playBtn;
private SeekBar seekbar;
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler handler;
int totaltime;

MediaPlayer player;

TextView storyname, writername;
ImageView image;
String nameStory, writerStory,link;
String imageStory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

    backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backbtn);
    playBtn = findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
    forBtn = findViewById(R.id.forbtn);
    handler = new Handler();
    seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekbar.setMax(totaltime);


    storyname = findViewById(R.id.audioStoryName);
    writername = findViewById(R.id.audioWriterName);
    image = findViewById(R.id.audioImage);

    nameStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyName");
    writerStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("writterName");
    imageStory = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyImage");
    link = getIntent().getStringExtra("storyLink");
    System.out.print(link);
    storyname.setText(nameStory);
    writername.setText(writerStory);
    Picasso.get().load(imageStory).fit().into(image);
    try{
        player=new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(link);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
        playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
        backBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_back_black_24dp);
        forBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_fast_black_24dp);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!player.isPlaying()){
                    player.start();

playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
                }else {
                    player.pause();

playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                }
            }
        });
        forBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition()+50000);
            }
        });
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition()-50000);
            }
        });
        totaltime = player.getDuration();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

}
}
```

Press the next button and it will play the immediate next song from the API.

Comment: your question is unclear please show your full code of how you're playing a song

Comment: this part is only for the next button code

Comment: please show me your code for playing music not next button

Comment: where i will send u the code?

Comment: that's a silly question post it here just edit your question

Comment: check it please

Comment: As per your code below answer is correct you should load your next song link in player.setdatasource

Comment: it's not working.
when i do this app is forcefully closed

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
int currentIndex = 0;

forBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentIndex++;  
            player.setDataSource(array.get(currentIndex));
        }
});
```

Comment: I need to play the next one from API
is it possible to enter the next path of all the songs?

Comment: will you please give me a demo to add about 5 songs path in this code?

Comment: implement this method in try catch.